# Number of pairs (a, b) such that a*b < N where a, b, N are integers greater than 0

Tags: c, math, counting

I have this code in C to calculate number of such pairs::

```
long long factors(int N) {
    int nr = (int) sqrt(N);
    int b;

    int fix = N - nr * nr - 1;
    long long ans = 0;
    for (b = 2; b <= nr; b++) {
        if (N % b == 0) {
            ans += N/b - 1;
        } else {
            ans += N/b;
        }
    }

    if ( fix < 0) {
        ans = (2*ans) + N + fix;
    } else {
        ans = (2*ans) + N + fix - 1;
    }

    return ans; 
}
```

This function correctly computes number of such pairs. What is the logic behind it?

Comment: I think this question fits better on [Stack Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @icecub: no, Code Review is for improvements to your own code, not explaining someone else's.

Comment: @immibis: I suggest not mathematics, as the code contains a number of tricks above and beyond the mathematical essence of the algorithm. OK here, I’d say!

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's why I said "fits better". According to OP, the code workes fine and no help is required (just explanation). So I thought it didn't fit on SO or on CR. But since "working" code discussion is more common on CR, I thought it fits better there. Anyway, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @icecub: that's why you need to read the [on-topic guide](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): *Am I an owner or maintainer of the code?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Illustrative diagram

Consider the following illustration of the case *N = 10*,
where each position represents a pair of factors to be counted,
`a`/`N`, `2` and `-`/`*` show the stages of the algorithm when the pair is counted (as explained below) and `.` is a placeholder to mark pairs that are not counted in the stage in question:

```
  | 1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
--+-~~~-===-===-----------------------
1 ! N2- a2- a2- .2. .2. .2. .2. .2. .2.
2 ! N2- a2- a2- .2.
3 ! N2- a2- a2*
4 | N.. a..
5 | N..
6 | N..
7 | N..
8 | N..
9 | N..
```

#### Explanation of the algorithm

What the algorithm effectively does, is:

- Count the columns from 2 up to *int (sqrt (N))* (i.e. 3 in the above case, marked with `=` and `a`).

  - Column *b* adds *N / b* unless *b* is a factor of *N*, in which case the last does not count.
- Add *N - 1* for the first column (marked with `~` and `N`).
- Double this, so as to cover the as yet uncounted rows (marked with `!` and `2`).
- Subtract the region counted twice (marked with `-`), which has size *nr<sup>2</sup>*, or one less if *nr<sup>2</sup> = N*, as in that case we will not have counted *(nr,nr)* (marked with `*` instead of `-`).

The calculation of `fix` and the last part of the code (and ) may be rearranged as follows, if we eliminate the calculation and test of `fix`:

```
    ans = ans + N - 1;              // Add in the first column
    ans = 2 * ans;                  // Double to cover rows as well

    if ( nr * nr != N )             // Equivalent to fix >= 0
        ans = ans -  nr * nr;       // Subtract the square region counted twice
    else
        ans = ans - (nr * nr - 1);  // We did not count (nr,nr)
```

#### Commented code

The posted code, mildly adapted (assuming C99 / MSVS 2012+) and commented:

```
long long factors(int N) {
    long long ans = 0;        // Result to return
    int nr = (int) sqrt(N);   // Highest possible value of the lower factor

    // Count factorisations (a,b) with a ∈ 2..√N
    for (int b = 2; b <= nr; b++) {
        if (N % b == 0) {    // If b | N ..
            ans += N/b - 1;  // .. then b*(N/b) = N, so count 1..(N/b - 1)
        } else {
            ans += N/b;      // .. count 1..N/b
        }
    }

    // Remaing steps of algorithm, optimised:
    // - Add N-1 for 1st column (1,1..(N-1)), giving total (a,b) with a ∈ 1..√N
    // - Double, to cover the reversed pairs (b,a) with a ∈ 1..√N, b ∈ √N..N
    // - Subtract nr² or nr²-1, for pairs counted twice
    int fix = N - nr * nr - 1;     // A correcting term, chosen to compare to 0
    if ( fix < 0) {                   // I.e. if nr² = N ..
        ans = (2*ans) + N + fix;      // .. ans = 2*(ans + N-1) - (nr² - 1)
    } else {
        ans = (2*ans) + N + fix - 1;  // .. ans = 2*(ans + N-1) - (nr²)
    }

    return ans; 
}
```

Comment: Glad it helped! Hope you like my last additions (do I get +1 as well?).

Answer (score 0):

The way it is happening is :

1. Square root is calculated. so if square root is no (say) and N is not a square then maximum permissible number that can multiply itself and be less than N is no.
2. We check if number is a square by fix variable.If number is a square then one possibility is less i.e, no*no=N which cannot be the case.So we subtract 1 as shown in the code :

   else {
           ans = (2*ans) + N + fix - 1;
            }
3. Next we run a loop from 2 to the square root finding the maximum no of elements which can be multiplied to each loop element and still be less than N.

   e.g,   let N be 15 
           for b=2 there can be N/2= 7 elements that can be multiplied to 2 and be less than 15
            2X1,2X2.........2X6,2X7  and we add 7 answers to ans
        . For b=3 N/3=5
            so there can be N/3-1 elements because 3*5=15 which is not allowed.
            3X1,3*2....3X4       and we add 4 answers to ans
         and so on to number no.
4. Now for every pair (a,b) there will be a pair (b,a) so we multiply ans by 2.
5. Upto now we have considered a and b upto N/2  as we have used the loop from 2.In this case(N=15) maximum a or b is 7 as shown.(2X7). There yet exists N/2 values which when multiplied to 1 is less than N.In this(N=15) case that is 8,9,10,11,12,13,14.  So there will be 2*(N/2) . ie, N cases to add to ans.
   So ans is added by N.
6. Finally we add fix to take care of the extra cases if it is not a square.